# Variant of rod cutting

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

You are given a wooden stick of length X with m markings on it at arbitrary places (integral), and the markings suggest where the cuts are to be made accordingly. For chopping a L-length stick
into two pieces, the carpenter charges L dollars (does not matter whether the two pieces are of equal length or not, i.e, the chopping cost is independent of where the chopping point is).
Design a dynamic programming algorithm that calculates the minimum overall cost.

Couldn't figure out the recurrence.
Was asked this in a recent programming interview.

Comment: it feels as if something is missing from this problem, may be a constraint. Generally DP problems have a constraint under which you have to minimise or maximise a quantity. Coz if the stick doesn't have to cut at all the markings and the price is independent of the length of the chopped wood, then the minimum price would be $L for chopping just once. Not sure, may be someone can correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The stick needs to be cut at all the markings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With m marks, you have m+2 interesting points, 0 = left end-point, marks 1, ..., m, right end-point = (m+1).
Store the distance from interesting point 0 to interesting point i in an array to calculate costs.
**Edit:** (Doh, gratuitously introduced an unnecessary loop, noticed after seeing Per's answer again)
For each `0 <= l < r <= m+1`, let `cost[l][r]` be the lowest cost for completely chopping the piece between points l and r. The solution is `cost[0][m+1]`.

```
// Setup
int pos[m+2];
pos[0] = 0; pos[m+1] = X;
for(i = 1; i <= m; ++i){
    pos[i] = position of i-th mark;
}
int cost[m+2][m+2] = {0};
for(l = 0; l < m; ++l){
    // for pieces with only one mark, there's no choice, cost is length
    cost[l][l+2] = pos[l+2]-pos[l];
}
// Now the dp
for(d = 3; d <= m+1; ++d){  // for increasing numbers of marks between left and right
    for(l = 0; l <= m+1-d; ++l){ // for all pieces needing d-1 cuts
        // what would it cost if we first chop at the left most mark?
        best_found = cost[l+1][l+d];
        for(i = l+2; i < l+d; ++i){ // for all choices of first cut, ssee if it's cheaper
            if (cost[l][i] + cost[i][l+d] < best_found){
                best_found = cost[l][i] + cost[i][l+d];
            }
        }
        // add cost of first chop
        cost[l][i][l+d] = (pos[l+d] - pos[l]) + best_found;
    }
}
return cost[0][m+1];
```

Complexity: If you're naively checking all possible ways to chop, that'd make m! ways. Very bad.
Taking into account that after any cut it doesn't matter whether you first completely chop the left part, then the right or interleave the chopping of the two parts, the complexity is (for m >= 2) reduced to `2*3^(m-2)`. Still very bad.
For our dp:

1. innermost loop, looping i; d-1 (l < i < l+d)
2. loop over l: m+2-d (0 <= l <= m+1-d), makes (m+2-d)*(d-1)
3. outermost loop, 3 <= d <= m+1, makes roughly m^3/6 steps.

Okay, O(m^3) isn't everybody's dream, but it's the best I could quickly come up with (after some inspiration from Per's post made me notice a prior inefficiency).

Comment: Cant understand the need for `pos[0] = 0; pos[m+1] = X`. Could you please elaborate why we need these two extra points? We cannot cut the array at these points anyway.

Comment: How do you magically convert cost into a 3D array in the last statement of the 3 nested for loops?

Answer (score 1):

Compute, for every pair of (marking|endpoint)s, the cheapest way to cut that segment of the rod. For each segment, minimize over the choice of first cuts in that segment.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want the carpenter to cut once, then keep cutting until the sticks are all cut, and you are asking for the order in which to make the cuts?

in that case, one way to do this is to do a depth-first recursive search through the tree of possible combinations, where you count the cost as you go, record the first sequence and its cost, and from that point forward, avoid descending into trees where the cost is higher and always record any cheaper sequences that you find.

Comment: I think you are talking about backtracking. It would be expensive for this case.
But the interviewer was looking for a DP solution.